# Prove that $1/a + 1/b - 1/c < 1/abc $, if $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}=5/3 $and $a,b,c>0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I can't figure this one out. I got that $bc+ab-ab<1$. How do we apply the known sum of squares? How is this one solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

$$bc+ac-ab<1$$

It's equal:

$$-2<2ab-2ac-2bc$$

Add $a^2+b^2+c^2$ to right side and $\frac{5}{3}$ to left (it's the same):

$$\frac{-1}{3}=-2+\frac{5}{3}<a^2+b^2+c^2-2ab-2ac+2bc=(a+b-c)^2$$

Now the inequality is obvious.